# Flink to implement a job which should start processing events once its parent job has done bootstrapping

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a use case to implement in which historic data processing needs to be done before my streaming job can start processing live events.

My streaming job will become part of already running system, which means data is already present. And this data first needs to be processed before my job starts processing the live streaming events.

So how should i design this, what i can think off are the following ways;
a) First process the historic data, once done than only start the streaming job.
b) Start the historic data processing & streaming job simultaneously. But keep buffering the events until the historic data has been processed.
c) Make one job having both the capabilities of historic data processing + streaming live events.

Pros & Cons of the above approaches;

1. Approach (a), simple but needs manual intervention. Plus as the historic data will take time to get loaded, and once done post that when i start the job what should be the flink consumer property to read from the stream - earliest, latest or timestamp based? Reason to think about it as the moment job starts it will be a fresh consumer with no offset/consumer group id registered with kafka broker (in my case it is Oracle streaming service)
2. Approach (b) buffer size should be large enough to withhold the events states. Also the window that will hold the events needs to buffer till 'x' timestamp value for the first time only while post that it should be 'y' value (ideally very very less than 'x' as the bootstrapping is already done) . How to make this possible?
3. Approach (c) sounds good, but historic processing is only for first time & most importantly post historic processing only buffered events need to be processed. So next time as no historic processing is reqd. so how would other stream knows that it should keep processing  the events as no historic processing is reqd.

Appreciate any help/suggestions to implement & design my use case better.

Answer (score 1):

The [`HybridSource`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/connectors/datastream/hybridsource/) is designed for this scenario. The current implementation has some limitations, but you may find it meets your needs.

Comment: thanks for your reply @David, in my case as one source is JDBC through which i need to bootstrap first followed by kafka source. what happens in case the bootstrapping goes beyond the kafka retention period.?

Answer (score 0):

You might go for the approach explained in the 2019 Flink Forward talk [A Tale of Dual Sources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTWntKy_MJs).

From what I remember, their situation was slightly different, in that they had two sources for the same data, a historic store (S3) and a queue with fresh events (Kafka), yet the data content and processing was the same.

- They attempted to write a custom source which read from both Kafka and S3 at the same time, but that failed due to some idiosyncrasies of Flink source initialization.
- They also did something like approach b, but the buffered data would often become way too large to handle.
- They ended up making one job that can read both sources, but only reads S3 at first, then terminates itself by throwing an exception, and upon being restarted by Flink, starts reading Kafka.

With this restarting trick, you can essentially get the advantages of a and c, without having to worry about needing any manual intervention for the switch.

Comment: Thanks @Caesar, this talk on dual source really helped to visualize potential hurdles & compare the approaches mentioned in my post.